# Singular Value Decomp inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let 
$\newcommand{\<}{\langle}$
$\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}$
$T \in L(V)$ be a linear operator on an n-dimensional real inner-product space of $(V,<.,.>)$ whose singular value decomposition is given by two orthonormal bases $(u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{n})$, $(v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n})$ of
$V$ and singulr values $\sigma_{1,},\sigma_{2},...,\sigma_{n} \geq 0$ such that
$Tx=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_{j}<x,v_{j}>u_{j}$.
Prove that for any $n <m$ we have $\| Tx - \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sigma_{j}<x,v_{j}>u_{j}\| \leq \sigma_{m+1}\|x\|$.

## My solution

$$\| Tx - \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sigma_{j}<x,v_{j}>u_{j}\|=\\
\|\sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\sigma_{j}<x,v_{j}>u_{j}\|=\\ 
\|\sigma_{m+1}<x,v_{m+1}>u_{m+1}+...+ \sigma_{n}<x,v_{n}>u_{n}\|=\\ \|\sigma_{m+1}<x,v_{m+1}>u_{m+1}\|+....+\|\sigma_{n}<x,v_{n}>u_{n}\|=\\
|\sigma_{m+1}<x,v_{m+1}>|\|u_{m+1}\|+...+|\sigma_{n}<x,v_{n}>|\|u_{n}\|=\\
|\sigma_{m+1}<x,v_{m+1}>|+...+|\sigma_{n}<x,v_{n}>|=\\
\sigma_{m+1}\|x\|\|v_{m+1}\|+...+\sigma_{n}\|x\|\|v_{n}\|=\\
\sigma_{m+1}\|x\|+...+\sigma_{n}\|x\|
$$
can anyone help?

Comment: Replace `<x,y>` in your question with `\<x,y\>` in order to get the correct brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable attempt, but this wasn't *quite* the correct trick.
$$
\begin{align}
\left\| 
Tx - \sum_{j=1}^m \sigma_j \<x,v_j\>u_j
\right\|^2 &= 
\left\| 
\sum_{j=m+1}^n \sigma_j \<x,v_j\>u_j
\right\|^2
 =
\sum_{j=m+1}^n \sigma_j^2 |\<x,v_j\>|^2 
\\ & \leq
\sum_{j=m+1}^n \sigma_{m+1}^2 |\<x,v_j\>|^2 
 =
\sigma_{m+1}^2 \sum_{j=m+1}^n  |\<x,v_j\>|^2 
\\ & \leq 
\sigma_{m+1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^n  |\<x,v_j\>|^2 
 =
\sigma_{m+1}^2 \|x\|^2
\end{align}
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: Wow that was easy @Omnomnomnom . Just had to square it

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know if you're interested in any of the formatting tricks I used here